# smoothState.js: Add class to #main wrapper

Tags: javascript, smoothstate.js

I am using smoothStates default settings and I wanted to know if I can add a class to the main wrapper so I can change the background color of the site? I don't want to add another div under main as its just extra markup.

At the moment I can only add page-index and then the rest of the pages don´t change as smoothState doesn't load the page again.

**EDIT:** So I want to add a class for each page, like: `page-index`, `page-about` and so on.

**I have a div like so:**

```
<div id="main">
 // stuff here
</div>
```

**When you click on /news:**

```
<div id="main" class="page-news">
 // stuff here
</div>
```

**My functions:**

```
$(function(){
'use strict';
var options = {
  prefetch: true,
  cacheLength: 2,
  onStart: {
    duration: 250, // Duration of our animation
    render: function ($container) {
      // Add your CSS animation reversing class
      $container.addClass('is-exiting');

      // Restart your animation
      smoothState.restartCSSAnimations();
    }
  },
  onReady: {
    duration: 0,
    render: function ($container, $newContent) {
      // Remove your CSS animation reversing class
      $container.removeClass('is-exiting');

      // Inject the new content
      $container.html($newContent);

    }
  }
},
smoothState = $('#main').smoothState(options).data('smoothState');
});
```

Comment: When do you want to add the class? After, before, in the middle of the animation?

Comment: Hi, from the start when people visit the home page.

Comment: What do you mean by that? After all animations are complete?

Comment: If you want to add the class when the visitor loads your site, then do not do that via smoothState. Then use `window.onload`

Comment: The thing is smoothState does not reload the page again, I can get the class names to change if I do a F5 then sure I see the changes, its just when you click from page to page it only shows me the page-index class.

Comment: Take a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you want, you can use `onAfter`.

> The function to run when the new content has been injected into the page and all animations are complete. This is when to re-initialize any plugins needed by the page.

Create a function:

```
function addClass() {
    $('#main').addClass('your_class second_class');
};
```

Then inject this into your smoothState initialization:

```
$(function(){
'use strict';
var options = {
  prefetch: true,
  cacheLength: 2,
  onStart: {
    duration: 250, // Duration of our animation
    render: function ($container) {
      // Add your CSS animation reversing class
      $container.addClass('is-exiting');

      // Restart your animation
      smoothState.restartCSSAnimations();
    }
  },
  onReady: {
    duration: 0,
    render: function ($container, $newContent) {
      // Remove your CSS animation reversing class
      $container.removeClass('is-exiting');

      // Inject the new content
      $container.html($newContent);

    }
  },
  onAfter: function($container, $newContent) {
    addClass();
  }
},
smoothState = $('#main').smoothState(options).data('smoothState');
});
```

---

**Update:** How to dynamically set classes:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="cms-classes" class="Put your classes in here">
</p>

/* CSS */
#cms-classes { display: none }

// JavaScript
function addClass() {
    cmsClasses = $('#cms-classes').attr('class');
    $('#main').addClass(cmsClasses);
};
```

---

Hope this helps!

[Reference](https://github.com/miguel-perez/smoothState.js?files=1#onafter)

Comment: @EmmaStone Sorry, I have no idea why I changed my answer from `onAfter` to `onReady` :)

Comment: No worries @jonhue :) I will try the code sample out tomorrow, just one quick question again, when you say: ".addClass('your_class second_class');"  I don´t know all of the classes as the class names come from the CMS I am working from... Can it not see if there is a class change and then add that change to the new page load? I am new to all of this for please forgive the silly questions :)

Comment: Well "CMS" I will use WordPress but also tried Jekyll but also no lucky (

Comment: I appended a way to 'dynamically' add classes to the answer.

Comment: Oh I see that's one way of doing it as well. I was playing around with jquery to change the page class and append it to the body but it didn't work for all pages (

Comment: Hi I tried it again today and still no luck, I need to see what is wrong with my code and to see if I have missed something, I appreciate your help!

Comment: The above snippet is working for me in my application